# Do you need to allow kernel extensions to use samsung t7 hardware on a Macbook pro M1 13 inch?

Tags: kernel, plugins

Do you need to allow kernel extensions to use  Samsung t7 hardware on a Macbook pro-M1 13-inch?

Comment: You cannot even _use_ kernel extensions on an M1. But that seems to be just a regular external SSD, so you just plug it in.

Comment: @DarkDust They are still a thing, though Apple are steering away from them. There will be a lot of legacy to transition. See https://eclecticlight.co/2020/12/15/extensions-big-sur-and-m1-macs/ , https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/deployment/depa5fb8376f/web and https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/sec8e454101b/web

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to change the Security Policy to "Allow user management of kernel extensions from identified developers." if you want to use Samsung's own encryption / lock and management app. It is a prerequisite of its install / use.

The install process is a bit wayward, even so that Samsung provided an extra document for a workaround when installing in macOS. Find it at https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/global.semi.static/Troubleshooting%20Guide%20for%20macOS%20Compatibility_Rev.1.1.pdf

The only benefit it might have provided me was to be able to update the T7 firmware. Other than that, macOS FileVault provides adequate security for me. The lock facility might be useful to you though, as while FileVault prevents someone having access to your data, a lock would prevent them from reformatting and reusing the SSD without a care for the data.

All that said, the T7 has been a reliable and fast target disk for Time Machine for me. I ended up just using it as-is without the Samsung software.